# CSS, JavaScript, HTML - Empty paragraphs and wrong code in WYSIWYG editors

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla, wysiwyg

I'm making a site for a client (just a new layout, site already exists, and it's done in Joomla 1.7). I've got a problem with articles, done via WYSIWYG editor by client. Why? Well, code it's pretty messed up. There are many empty tags, like:

```
<p></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

or even:

```
<p><span style="color: #008000;"><span style="font-size: medium;"><strong> </strong></span></span></p>
```

Can I remove it somehow with JavaScript or CSS? Or maybe I shouldn't care, since I can't control the way client uses editor?

EDIT: So, solution by kitgui.com did the trick - check out this plugin - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/ - works like a charm.

Comment: Are you able to edit the file directly? I would open it with an editor like NotePad++, Crimson Editor or something like that and just manually remove all the junk code.

Comment: This sounds like a WYSINotWYG

Comment: @BumbleB2na a lot of old WYSIWYG, like DreamWeaver, used to do a lot of this bloat code.

Comment: @Biotox Well, I would do that, but there are already hundreds of articles. Doing that by hand would take ages.

Comment: This is just how WYSIWYGs works.

Comment: @Irminsul you can just use the replace all function or the find/replace to loop through them. I think Crimson Editor can do batch files.

Comment: My appologies, I missed the part about updating a site with existing content and didn't know this was a question regarding cleanup!

Comment: @Biotox - Do you mean replacing wrong code once, for example in database? BTW. Joomla 1.7.1 uses TinyMCE editor, version 3.4.4

Comment: @Irminsul Ah, it's in a database. Yes, I meant just clean it all up once. But, it might not be worth it if the newly added stuff will just get the same empty/bloat code.

Comment: Yes, the new stuff is the biggest problem - because client, doesn't know anything about codes and "HTML" sounds like a black magic to that person. It seems that you have to know HTML anyway to use WYSIWYG editors properly - unfortunately.

Comment: Solution by kitgui.com did the trick for me. That jQuery plugin gives very clean code.

Comment: I had a similar problem in a shopping cart where the WYSIWYG editor for product descriptions would add <p> tags when I did not enter them. My solution was to wrap the copy in <div> tags and it would render properly without the <p> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David made a good suggestion but I didn't see if you were doing PHP or not. If you want to try JavaScript post processing you could try applying:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/

at the end before saving..

Comment: Great! This plugin did the trick, removing even weird code, like: `<p><span style="color: #008000;"><span style="font-size: medium;"><strong> </strong></span></span></p>`  . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement some postprocessing when saving, using the [Tidy class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php). Tidy has lots of configuration options and you can clean up those empty tags with only a few lines of code.

Something like:

```
<?php
$html = "MESSY HTML HERE";
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html);
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
?>
```

Comment: Is this a PHP solution though. I still gave +1.

Comment: Well yes, I thought this makes sense, because Joomla runs on php.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't have any PHP knowledge, and don't know where to put that code.

Comment: Even if you don't have PHP knowledge there might be one of the Joomla extensions in the extension directory that is suitable for you. http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=tidy